# Data binding in WPF DataGrid is not displayed on the form

Tags: c#, database, wpf

Data ist displayed from the database on the form. What's wrong?

I make Repository, forms and few method. I use use SQLite and want display result on the form of simple query like SELECT id, Name FROM Students
i put button on the form whith code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var repo = new StudentsRepository();
            var res = repo.GetAll();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("students");
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
```

form have DataGrid and 2 column but im not undertand why on form not displayed results

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="352" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="758" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Width="100" Header="Id"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100" Header="Name"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="ShowDataButton" Content="Show_Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="64,367,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

```
public class StudentsRepository: IRepository<StudentEntity>
    {
        private string GET_ALL_QUERY = "SELECT id, Name FROM Students";
        private SqliteContext DbContext { get; }

        public StudentsRepository()
        {
            DbContext = new SqliteContext();
        }
        public async Task<IList<StudentEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable("Students");
            using (var conn = await DbContext.GetConnection())
            {
                var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(GET_ALL_QUERY, conn);
                da.Fill(dataTable);

                conn.Close();
            }

            var studList = new List<StudentEntity>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                studList.Add(new StudentEntity(row));
            }

            return studList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataTable()
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable("Students");
    using (var conn = await DbContext.GetConnection())
    {
        var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(GET_ALL_QUERY, conn);
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
    }
    return dataTable;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var repo = new StudentsRepository();
    var res = repo.GetDataTable();
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = res.Result.AsDataView();
}
```

Hope this helps~

Updated:
Sorry, function return type is task therefore its not actual data, this would do: `res.Result.AsDataView();`

Comment: @Елена sorry, can you try to use `res.Result.AsDataView();`

Answer (score 0):

On your DataGrid set:

```
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

Then change:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
```

To:

```
DataGrid1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView
```

In WPF using Bindings with your defined columns requires you to set a DataContext instead of an ItemSource. Personally I've always worked with .ToList() when pulling from a database and displaying data in a DataGrid so I can't comment on the rest of your code with regards to the DataTable.